# Connecting to S3 Bucket through Custom API Gateway using Java AWS S3 SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I am new to AWS S3 and would like to understand how can I connect to S3 API through a Custom API Gateway (this is my company specific gateway not Amazon API Gateway).

To set the context, I have created an S3 bucket and uploaded a sample file in the bucket. Using the code below, I was able to connect directly to the S3 bucket and fetch the details of my file. But due to security reasons, we cannot connect directly to the S3 Bucket. Hence, we have a CA API Gateway in middle. I have used the Amazon S3 Client class and used `s3Client.setEndPoint()` method to pass in the gateway URL but do not see any hit at the gateway. Regardless I am able to get the file details, it looks like the URL I mentioned in the setEndpoint method is being ignored.

The call flow should be something like this:

> Java Code --> API Gateway --> S3 Bucket

but currently it is something like this

> Java Code --> S3 Bucket.

Below is the code I am using:

Code:

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("<Access Key>", "+<Secret Key>"); 
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
client.setEndpoint("<Gateway URL Here>");
client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2));

//Get Object from S3
client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("<Bucket Name>", "<File Name>"), new File("
<Destination Path>"));
```

Comment: what this question has to do with apache-camel?